# Custom CSS/JS combined to webform custom component gives type MIME error

Tags: webforms, 10

I've made a custom Webform component, working well so far. A javascript library is attached to this component.

```
$elements['#attached']['library'][] = 'my_module/my_lib';
```

My client tried to add custom css and js but here **/admin/webform/manage/webform_id/settings/assets** for some reason , he has this error :

```
Resource from « https://xyz.com/webform/css/webform_id?s4muhb » was blocked because of type MIME (« text/html ») incorrect (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).
```

After digging and testing, it seems like this part of the code is generating the error:

```
$route = Url::fromRoute('my_module.custom_ajax_route');
$elements['#attached']['drupalSettings']['my_module']['url'] = $route->toString();
```

If instead of *$route->toString()* I set the route '*/theroute*' and clear the cache, the custom css is working fine.

I'm using Drupal 10.1.4, apache and webform 6.2

---

EDIT

FYO, my function is a generic static function that generate field

```
public static function generateMyFields() ...
```